# Audio recorded on raspberry pi has higher pace and lot of breakage

Tags: speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3, pyaudio

I am trying to record voice using python. For this, I have used [Uberi](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) speech_recognition.

Using the code shown below, when I run it on my mac, I can observe that the audio is quite clear and at a normal pace. But when I run the code on raspberry pi, the audio pace is increased and also the audio has some kind of breakage in between.

Can someone guide why this is happening and how can I rectify so that it works on raspberry pi too.

Note* - The functions definitions like listen(), get_raw_data() etc, that are called in the below code are present in this [file](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py).

Audio files are present [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vQ1Ytr_v_biQU65wVSDWjkwsz39zz_Dl). File1 is recorded on mac, file2 and file3 are recorded on the raspberry pi.

Thanks

Code sample:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import logging
import requests
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import json
import datetime
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

logging.basicConfig(filename='assistant3_logs.log', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)

def forwardRequestToPfivaSpeechClient(serverAddress, audioRawFilename, api, language, user):
    try:
        url = 'http://' + serverAddress + '/data/ingestion/speech-to-text'
        with open(audioRawFilename, 'rb') as f:
            files = {'file' : f}
            requests.post(url, files=files, data={"api": api, "language": language, "user": user})
        #requests.post(url, data={"fileName": fileName, "api": api, "language": language, "user": user})
        logger.info('Request forwarded to PFIVA server')
    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        logger.error('Error forwarding request to PFIVA server {0}'. format(e))


def parseLanguageForSpeech(speechLanguage):
    speechLanguage = speechLanguage.lower();

    if speechLanguage == 'english':
        return 'en-US'
    elif speechLanguage == 'german':
        return 'de-DE'
    elif speechLanguage == 'french':
        return 'fr-FR'
    elif speechLanguage == 'hindi':
        return 'hi-IN'
    else:
        logger.error('Language not supported')
        exit()


def main(speechLanguage, api, user, serverAddress):
    try:
        audioDirectoryPath = '/Users/john/audioDumps'
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(audioDirectoryPath):
                os.mkdir(audioDirectoryPath)
                logger.info('Audio directory does not exists, created')
            else:
                logger.info('Audio directory already exists')
        except OSError:
            logger.info('Error creating directory ' + audioDirectoryPath)
            exit()

        logger.info('Initiating speech recognition.')
        with m as source: r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        logger.info('Setting minimum energy threshold to [' + format(r.energy_threshold) + ']')
        while True:
            GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
            logger.info('Waiting for user query')
            # After 5 secs, cut off listening
            with m as source: audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=5)
            if audio is not None:
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
                logger.info('Audio captured, getting raw and wav data.')
                rawData = audio.get_raw_data(convert_rate=16000, convert_width=2)
                wavData = audio.get_wav_data(convert_rate=16000, convert_width=2)

                currentDateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%S")
                try:
                    path = audioDirectoryPath + '/' + currentDateTime
                    logger.info('Creating directory : ' + path) 
                    os.mkdir(path)
                except OSError:
                    logger.info('Error creating directory ' + path)
                    exit()

                outputRawFilename = path + "/" + currentDateTime + ".raw"
                outputRawFile = open(outputRawFilename,"wb")
                outputRawFile.write(rawData)
                outputRawFile.close()
                logger.info('Audio data written to a raw file')

                outputWavFilename = path + "/" + currentDateTime + ".wav"
                outputWavFile = open(outputWavFilename,"wb")
                outputWavFile.write(wavData)
                outputWavFile.close()
                logger.info('Audio data written to a wav file')

                #forwardRequestToPfivaSpeechClient(serverAddress, currentDateTime, api, parseLanguageForSpeech(speechLanguage), user)
                forwardRequestToPfivaSpeechClient(serverAddress, outputRawFilename, api, parseLanguageForSpeech(speechLanguage), user)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--language", dest="language", help="Specify language for voice assistant", required=False, default="english")
    parser.add_argument("--api", dest="api", help="Specify API for voice assistant", required=False, default="GoogleCloudSpeech")
    parser.add_argument("--serverAddress", dest="serverAddress", help="Specify address for PFIVA server", required=False, default="rasp-pf.de")
    parser.add_argument("--user", dest="user", help="Specify user for voice assistant", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    logger.info('Language : ' + str(args.language))
    logger.info('API : ' + str(args.api))
    logger.info('User : ' + str(args.user))
    logger.info('PFIVA server address : ' + str(args.serverAddress))
    main(args.language, args.api, args.user, args.serverAddress)
```

Comment: try convert_width=1 and see if that make difference.

Comment: using convert_width=1 adds a lot of noise plus it does not makes the audio pace to normal

Comment: It is possible that mic you are using with raspi is not supporting sample rate 16000 directly. Check alsa config on raspi and see if you need any alsa rate_converter or plug plugin.